# How to implement the function max_leaf_path(d) that find the key path through the nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

A nested dictionary is given where non dictionary values are integers (the leaf values), find the key path through the nested dictionary that returns the largest integer.

```
d={
    'a': {
        '1': 10,
        '2': 20,
        '3': 30,
    },
    'b': {
        'c': {
            '1': 100,
            '2': 200,
            '3': 300
        }
    },
    'c': {}
}
```

Also I should implement the function `path_value(dictionary,path)` that returns the value in the nested dictionary structure by following the path.

```
max_leaf_path(d) # returns ['b', 'c', '3']

path_value(d,['b', 'c', '3'])==300
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting homework problem. What have you tried in your efforts to solve it?

Comment: I used a for loop over the nested dictionary , but i didn't know how to use a condition for that..

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that can flatten the nested dict. Then you can easily find the max value and the key corresponding to it

```
>>> d = { 'a': { '1': 10, '2': 20, '3': 30, }, 'b': { 'c': { '1': 100, '2': 200, '3': 300 } }, 'c': {} }
>>> 
>>> flatten = lambda d, pref='': {k2:v2 for k,v in d.items() for k2,v2 in (flatten(v, pref+k) if isinstance(v, dict) else {pref+k:v}).items()}
>>> 
>>> max_leaf_path = lambda d: list(max(flatten(d).items(), key=lambda t: t[1])[0])
>>> max_leaf_path(d)
['b', 'c', '3']
>>> 
>>> path_value = lambda d, l: path_value(d[l[0]], l[1:]) if l else d
>>> path_value(d, ['b', 'c', '3'])
300
```